# Can I make a Poisson process by combining several non-Poisson processes?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stationary-processes

I'm interested to know if I can split a Poisson process into non-Poissonian sub-processes or not. Or equivalently, I want to know if an (ensemble) Poisson process can be produced by other-none Poissonian processes or not.

Note:

- I don't care about the number of processes, as long as it remains countable.
- A simple (counter) example that shows the (lack of) existence of such sub-processes is enough for me, although, of course, more advanced resources are very welcome.

Comment: Yes, take $N(t)$ a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda>0$ and define $Y(t) = \min[N(t), 2]$ and $Z(t) = N(t)-Y(t)$.  Then $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$ are not Poisson processes but $Y(t) + Z(t) = N(t)$. Or simply take $N(t) = N(t)/2 + N(t)/2$ and $N(t)/2$ is not a Poisson process.

Comment: This clear example can be the answer @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This summarizes my comments and gives another example.
Define $N(t)$ as a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda>0$.

1. If you do not require the sub-processes to be independent, you can take $$N(t) = N(t)/2 + N(t)/2$$ and $N(t)/2$ is not Poisson since it can take non-integer values. You can also take anything, like $Y(t) = \min[N(t), 2]$ and $Z(t) = N(t) - Y(t)$, and then $N(t) =Y(t) + Z(t)$.
2. If you want $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$ to be independent, you can take $Y(t) = -5$ and $Z(t) = N(t) + 5$.
3. For a more interesting example with $Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$ independent, you can take $Y(t)$ as the accumulated arrivals over $[0,1]$ and $Z(t)$ the accumulated arrivals over $(1, \infty)$, and $N(t) = Y(t) + Z(t)$:

\begin{align}
Y(t) &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
N(t) & \mbox{ if $t \leq 1$} \\
N(1) & \mbox{ else}\end{array}\right. \\
Z(t) &=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \mbox{ if $t \leq 1$} \\
N(t)-N(1) & \mbox{ else}\end{array}\right. \\
\end{align}

Comment: In the third example, $Y$ and $Z$ are nonhomogeneous Poisson processes. Perhaps the validity of this example hinges on whether OP accepts nonhomogeneous cases or not.

Comment: Yes, that can be viewed as a time inhomogeneous Poisson process with a time varying $\lambda(t)$ parameter.